# Eating meat mantra

Tags: food, vegetarianism, mantra

I heard from some brotherhood from Mahayana said Theravada also will do some chanting for eating meat. Is it true ?

I have only able to find the Mahayana Mantra but not Theravada info as below

https://drukpachoegon.org/meat-blessing-mantra

Comment: I can't find the reference but iirc it is canonical for Theravada that the Buddha said something like: 'should a bhikkhu eat meat without reflecting on what it is, is an offense of wrong-doing'.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "mantra" in the Theravada tradition for this as far as I am aware.

But the practitioner can mindfully reflect on what was taught in the suttas about food, before eating.

> "'This body, sister, comes into being through food. And yet it is by
> relying on food that food is to be abandoned.' Thus was it said. And
> in reference to what was it said? There is the case, sister, where a
> monk, considering it thoughtfully, takes food — not playfully, nor for
> intoxication, nor for putting on bulk, nor for beautification — but
> simply for the survival & continuance of this body, for ending its
> afflictions, for the support of the holy life, [thinking,] 'Thus will
> I destroy old feelings [of hunger] and not create new feelings [from
> overeating]. I will maintain myself, be blameless, & live in comfort.'
> Then he eventually abandons food, having relied on food. 'This body,
> sister, comes into being through food. And yet it is by relying on
> food that food is to be abandoned.' Thus was it said, and in reference
> to this was it said.
> [AN 4.159](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.159.than.html)

> "And how is physical food to be regarded? Suppose a couple, husband &
> wife, taking meager provisions, were to travel through a desert. With
> them would be their only baby son, dear & appealing. Then the meager
> provisions of the couple going through the desert would be used up &
> depleted while there was still a stretch of the desert yet to be
> crossed. The thought would occur to them, 'Our meager provisions are
> used up & depleted while there is still a stretch of this desert yet
> to be crossed. What if we were to kill this only baby son of ours,
> dear & appealing, and make dried meat & jerky. That way — chewing on
> the flesh of our son — at least the two of us would make it through
> this desert. Otherwise, all three of us would perish.' So they would
> kill their only baby son, loved & endearing, and make dried meat &
> jerky. Chewing on the flesh of their son, they would make it through
> the desert. While eating the flesh of their only son, they would beat
> their breasts, [crying,] 'Where have you gone, our only baby son?
> Where have you gone, our only baby son?' Now what do you think, monks:
> Would that couple eat that food playfully or for intoxication, or for
> putting on bulk, or for beautification?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "Wouldn't they eat that food simply for the sake of making it through
> that desert?"
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "In the same way, I tell you, is the nutriment of physical food to be
> regarded. When physical food is comprehended, passion for the five
> strings of sensuality is comprehended. When passion for the five
> strings of sensuality is comprehended, there is no fetter bound by
> which a disciple of the noble ones would come back again to this
> world.
> [SN 12.63](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.063.than.html)

Answer (score 0):

**I heard from some brotherhood from Mahayana said Theravada also will do some chanting for eating meat. Is it true ?**

As far as I understand, Theravada monastics will sometimes chant prior to eating for reflective purposes (i.e. to reinforce how they are suppose to appropriately observe and use their alms). Aside from that, Theravada Buddhism does not have any chants I have ever encountered that specifically involve meat eating.

---

I hope this answer helps. May you be well.